# How to change the style element html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My need to after load page paint over text tag `<a>` in
, but I've can't this do because of this style

doesn't change the colour. I've don't know how to remove this style. This is what I've tried.

```js
var ParsLocat = window.location.href.replace(window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1), '').split('&');
var ParsRazd = ParsLocat[0].split('=');
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
navA = nav.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < navA.length; i++) {
    var navAS = navA[i].children[0].search.split('&')
    var navRaz = navAS[0].split('=');
    if (ParsRazd[1] == navRaz[1]) {
       navA[i].style.cssText = "color:white;";
        break;
    }
}
```

```css
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #9d9d9d;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
    <li ><a >Архивная отчетность</a></li>
    <li ><a >Мониторинг</a></li>
</ul>
```

Where am I doing it wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't add `!important` unless you have no other choice.Most of the time there is a better solution. What is the css selector that over rules your property?

Comment: Mark Baijens, I don't konw what you mean by the "the css selector that over rules your property" but I using bootstrap.

Comment: It was more an answer to the comment that is now deleted which recommended to use the `!important` tag. This is mostly a bad way to go. Your problem however was that you changed to wrong element, so kinda irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `color` of your anchor (`a`) is set to `#9d9d9d`, you will need to change the `color` of your `a` to `white`, not your `li`.

```js
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
navA = nav.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < navA.length; i++) {
    navA[i].children[ 0 ].style.color = "white";
    break;
}
```

```css
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #9d9d9d;
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
    <li ><a >Архивная отчетность</a></li>
    <li ><a >Мониторинг</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

change

```
navA[i].style.cssText = "color:white;";
```

to

```
navA[i].children[0].style.color = "white";
```

Comment: Because it does not work. Still changes the color on the `li` element instead of the `a` element. I recommend testing your solution before posting it.

Comment: Upvoted again :s It would work if it is on the right place for sure

Comment: @SandroSchaurer `navA = nav.getElementsByTagName('li');` stores a list of `li` elements. The OP wants to change the `a` element. So no it will not work. Just change the line in the snippet and you will see it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

`.navbar-nav > li {
    color: #9d9d9d;
}`

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
navA[i].children[0].style.cssText = "color:white;";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the style like this:

```
navA[i].setAttribute('style', 'color: white;');
```

Comment: the attribute added but the color doesn't change